# Failed to parse webhook JSON response: Cannot find field: responseId in message google.cloud.dialogflow.v2.WebhookResponse

Tags: asp.net-web-api, chatbot, dialogflow-es, fulfillment

I am creating a simple web chatbot with DialogFlow API V2.0 and ASP.NET WebAPI (.NET 4.5).

Questions:

1. the enclosed screenshot looks weird, can anyone show me the actual Fulfillment respons and JSON response looks like.
2. I am writing my own response, do i have to install any SDK for this ?

Error Message:
Webhook call failed. Error: Failed to parse webhook JSON response: Cannot find field: responseId in message google.cloud.dialogflow.v2.WebhookResponse.

[image]

Comment: I see two foreign characters in the response. That’s probably what’s making it not able to be parsed

Comment: Yes, that what I wondering what if my response is not valid . But in fiddler I don’t see these character, can u share you fulfilment response ?

Comment: Here is an example of a valid v2 webhook response: https://github.com/dialogflow/fulfillment-webhook-json/blob/master/responses/v2/response.json you shoudn't need to provide a responseId in your webhook response

Answer (score 0):

Just add MediaTypeHeaderValue "application/json" to your Headers Content of your HttpResponseMessage

```
HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
```